# correctly labeling incoming pop emails in gmail

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have one gmail account and one google apps mail account. For archiving (and searching) purposes I pull all of the apps mail to the gmail account using the POP feature. I have "leave a copy on server" ON and "archive incoming messages" ON. (So that I can read new messages). It works fine, except for messages where the "to:" field is some mailing list. The function to archive the downloaded messages seems to fail on those mails. Now the question, is this also your experience? Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: Correcting myself. The archive function seems to work, but the "Label incoming messagges: somelabel" does NOT in this circumstances.

Comment: Are there any other headers in the "Original Message" view that only occur in POP retrieved emails which originated from the mailing list?

Answer (score 3):

In a different mail application, I was able to filter on the `X-Apparently-To:` field of the message. This got me to thinking, and I found this article:

- [Three Undocumented Gmail Filters](http://www.articlesbase.com/internet-articles/three-undocumented-gmail-filters-746233.html)

which references this gmail support page

- http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190

and reveals that the equivalent seems to be **deliveredto:** advanced search directive.

To use *deliveredto:* in a search:

1. In the searchbox, type something like `deliveredto:myemail@pop-server.com`

To use *deliveredto:* in a filter:

1. Start creating a filter
2. In the **Has the words** box, type something like `deliveredto:myemail@pop-server.com`
3. Test the filter

The above referenced articles provide a number of advanced search directives to play with. If you're curious about the details of the email message for the different directives, you can use the **show original** menu option for the message. This option is found in the pull-down menu next to the inline **Reply** button, down below the **Reply to all** and **Forward** menu options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It lead me to realize a configuration mistake. However the "deliveredto:" directive only works for the topmost occurence in the email message. (which is always my gmail addres ). As a result cannot be used for correct labeling :-(.

Comment: It seems the link to the first article no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Crude, heavy-handing way of dealing: Create a filter for each mailing list to which you subscribe.